# Separation of Variables in PDEs, regarding the separation constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I know the mechanics behind the separation of variables and how it is used to solve PDEs; however, I am confused by the assumption behind the separation constant.

Taking the wave equation as an example:
    $\frac{d^2(u)}{dt^2} =c^2\frac{d^2(u)}{dx^2}$
with the separation of variables, where $u(t,x)=X(x)T(t)$ we derive the expression: $\frac{T''}{T}=c^2\frac{X''}{X}=\omega$ where $\omega$ is the separation constant.

So here, many texts and videos state that since the left hand side is a function of only time and the right hand side is a function of only space (x); therefore, the $\omega$ has to be a constant.

I am confused about $c^2$, from the derivation of the wave equation we know that $c$ represents the velocity and is not dimensionless. So why is it not taken into consideration? Have I overlooked something? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to repeat the argument so that 
 $$\frac{T''}{T}=c^2\frac{X''}{X}=\omega=\text{constant}$$ 
You have well set out the argument.

More generally, consider the next PDE :
$$\frac{d^2(u)}{dt^2} =\left(c_1(x)c_2(y)\right)^2\frac{d^2(u)}{dx^2}$$
where $c$ is no longer a constant but the product of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$. The separation of variables leads to :
$$\frac{1}{\left(c_2(y)\right)^2}\frac{T''}{T}=\left(c_1(x)\right)^2\frac{X''}{X}=\omega=\text{constant}$$
$\omega$ is any constant. There is no reason to say that a constant $\omega$ be related to a function $c_1(x)$ or to another function $c_2(y)$. So, it would be senseless to ask " Why $c_1$ or $c_2$ are not taken into consideration? ".

That is the same for the simpler case where $c_1(x)=c=$constant and $c_2(x)=1$.

In fact $c$ is effectively taken into consideration, but not at this step of calculus. It is taken into consideration at next step when the equation $c^2\frac{X''}{X}=\omega$ is solved.

For each value of $\omega$ the solutions involve $c$. They are as many solutions with $c$ into them than they are different $\omega$ and also the linear combinations of those solutions. So, they are an infinity of solutions until no boundary conditions is specified.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I understand that c1 and c2 are taken into consideration in the next step but why is it correct to state that the LHS is a function of only time and the RHS is a function of only x, when c1 and c2 have dimensions? This seems to be the basis for justifying equating it to a constant. Or does the method simply assume that they equate to a constant? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If we chose to apply the method of separation of variables, we assume that the separation is possible which implies that the separated terms are constant, what ever each one is as function of each respective variable. If it is not the case, the method of separation of variables fails (cannot be applied) and we have to try other methods. If it is the case (that is when the separation effectively occurs, the method of separation of variables is likely to leads to particular solutions which satisfy the PDE. But this doesn't mean that all solutions are obtained.

Answer (score 0):

$c$ isn't taken into consideration because to get to this linear form of the wave equation from the derivation, $c$ is assumed to be constant. The dimensions of $c$ just ensure that the equation is dimensionally consistent. When authors say the left-hand side is only a function of $t$ and the right-hand side is only a function of $x$, they mean to say
$$
\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}\right)}_{0} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(c^2\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}\right)
$$
and also
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(c^2\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}\right) = c^2\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}\right)}_{0}..
$$
Thus the equation is constant in both space and time.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{T''}{T}=c^2\frac{X''}{X}$ is a constant that does not depend on $x$ or $t$ iff $\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{T''}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}$ is a constant that does not depend on $x$ or $t$. If the first constant is $C$ and the second is $D$, then $c^2D=C$. The constants $C$ and $D$ are not arbitrary; they are determined by endpoint conditions, and no matter where you put the constant $c^2$, the solutions will be the same, and the $c^2$ will be properly incorporated into the problem.